# Facebook logout issue in another activity

Tags: android, facebook, google-plus

I am implementing google+ and facebook integration in my android app. After login through facebook or google+, next activity will come. In that activity how can i manage both facebook and google+ logout using my logout button?

```
public void googlePlusLogout() {
if (LoginActivity.mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(LoginActivity.mGoogleApiClient);
LoginActivity.mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
   }
} // Update - coed formatting

public void facebookLogout(){
LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
}
```

facebooklogout method is working fine. But if i call google+ logout method it is not working.

Comment: do u want two separate logout ??

Comment: Yes. Actually i have 3 separate logouts. I have to manage all the three logouts i.e., facebook, google+ and my app login, should be implement in one logout button.

Answer (score 1):

call this function for Google Plus Logout

```
 private void googlePlusLogout() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null)
            if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
                mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
    }
```

Comment: getting mGoogleApiClient is null

Comment: In loginactivity i have kept public static for GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient; by using class name i am getting mGoogleApiClient

Comment: If i remove static how can i access it  in another activity?

Comment: i am using this link http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Now i am getting logout. I have again added this code in my another activity   mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
.addConnectionCallbacks(this)
.addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API)
.addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();

Comment: hi brother, one more help in fb integration. how can i get emailid. List permissions = new ArrayList();
permissions.add(“email”);

Add all the permissions you need and then
loginButton.setReadPermissions(permissions); i am not getting if i use that

Comment: Brother dont misunderstand me. I am having only 4 reputation

Comment: bro i have done that only. but it is saying thanks for ur feedback. once you have 15 reputation your vote will be changed .....

Comment: System.out.println(profile.getFirstName());
System.out.println(profile.getLastName());
System.out.println(profile.getId());
System.out.println(profile.getName()); getting these informations but not emailid

Comment: facebook brother. Getting email id ..Now.

Comment: Hi bro, i have one doubt regarding facebook key hash generation. I have generated hashkey and kept in facebook developer console. Every thing is working fine. But do i need to regenerate hashkey for app release?

Comment: Previously i have generated using one class Application.java found in google search. Now How can i do release key hash?

Comment: Means same Application.java will provide the another key after apk is signed. Am i correct bro.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response bro. I'll do like that, i'll tell u

Comment: Bro, i didnt get any hashkey while signing apk, After sign the apk, executed the app. getting same hashkey

Comment: follow this link for answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17423870/is-there-any-way-to-get-key-hash-from-signed-apk

Comment: Bro..Now i have reputation >15.I have accepted your answer.

Comment: Having one problem related to imageview scaling

Comment: i have bitmap size width 440 and height 660. and also have xy coordinates(client location), all are getting from server. now my problem if i change the size of imageview then xy coordinates are not on same position. How to solve this issue?

Comment: bro. My question is i am getting one image from server, image width is 440 and height is 660.  And also i am getting xy coordinates from server nothing but client location. working fine in phones. If i run that app in tabs, working fine, but my requirement is that imageview have to fill the full screen in that case those xy coordinates are not on same position. So how to calculate  those imageview size and xy coordinates for tablets?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108936/discussion-between-user5594218-and-bajirao-shinde).

Comment: Hi bro, I am getting one issue. i.e., i have to show 2 scenarios on bitmap. one is user location, second is direction to particular location. I am getting individually two scenarios. But if i combine two scenarios i.e, if i show direction to path user location is path point is overriding. How to solve this issue. Please help me, any one scenario is working at a time

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
 public void  signoutGoogle(){

            Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                   new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                       @Override
                       public void onResult(Status status) {

                           Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                           startActivity(intent);


                       }
                   });
       }
```