# Android Installation failed - Same package but a different signature

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, signature, android-keystore

I have my release app (from Google play ) installed on the device. When I am trying to install the app via run in Android studio , I get this error .

I changed nothing ,It always worked, I always checked the release version before uploading the apk to Google play .

I thought maybe uploading to Google play will resolve the issue so I uploaded an alpha version (didn't want to take the risk of uploading to production so my users won't be enforced to uninstall first)
But my alpha testers get this:

[image: google play error message]

, I believe that if I upload the apk to production it will be the same.

1. What could lead to the difference in the signatures?
2. How can I check what is the difference?

Answer (score 2):

So let's answer your question in reverse order.

2. How can you check the difference?

You can check the difference by [pulling the APK off the device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11012976/get-apk-of-installed-app/11013175), then [looking at the certificate hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17423870/is-there-any-way-to-get-key-hash-from-signed-apk).

1. What could cause it?

Lots of things - here's two:

- you changed your local keystore (or deleted it) and Android Studio generated you a new one
- you enrolled in [Google Play App Signing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423) so the signature on the delivered APK is different from the signature on the APK you uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you have the same package, if you have a different `buildType` the phone won't allow it to install without uninstalling the previous version.

I had the same issue with HockeyApp, and uninstalling the existing version on the phone fixed it.

Comment: I ran it with the same build type , release

Comment: What's the error you get in Android Studio? Your question doesn't seem to have that info.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `signed release version` already installed on your device, Thus you can't install an `unsigned debug version`.
My solution is to **uninstall** current package from device (and also clear it's data to make sure) and then **retry** running via android studio.