# Facebook login in my application is no longer working after exporting it

Tags: android, facebook, export

I am using Facebook SDK 3.0 for developing an Android application that includes Facebook login.

I use such function to Login using Facebook:

```
    public void login(final ProgressDialog dialog) {

    Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (session.isOpened()) {
                AppSettings.facebookAuthToken = session.getAccessToken();

                Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,
                        new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                                    Response response) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                if (user != null) {

                                    Log.e("gavau", "kazka");

                                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                                    TimeZone tz = cal.getTimeZone();

                                    RequestParams a = new RequestParams();
                                    // a.put("foo", "bar");
                                    a.put("tz",
                                            ""
                                                    + (tz.getRawOffset() + tz
                                                            .getDSTSavings())
                                                    / 1000);

                                    a.put("fb_id", user.getId());
                                    a.put("fb_authkey",
                                            AppSettings.facebookAuthToken);
                                    Log.e("siunciu", a.toString());

                                    AppSettings.facebookId = user.getId();

                                    NetworkClient.receiveJSON("register/",
                                            a,
                                            new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

                                                @Override
                                                public void onSuccess(
                                                        String a) {
                                                    Log.e("gavau", a);
                                                    if (a.equals("0")) {
                                                        Toast.makeText(
                                                                getApplicationContext(),
                                                                "Hi, everything's OK!",
                                                                0).show();

                                                        AppSettings.logged = true;

                                                        onLogin(dialog);
                                                    }

                                                    else
                                                        Toast.makeText(
                                                                getApplicationContext(),
                                                                "bėda " + a,
                                                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                                }
                                            });

                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                            " User is equal to NULL!", 0)
                                            .show();
                                }

                            }
                        });
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Session is not opened", 1).show();

            }

        }
    });
}
```

Everything works fine while developing the application, but I after exporting the application Facebook login is no more working (I got toast *"Session is not opened"*) and *Facebook login dialog is not shown.* 
If I run the project on mobile phone using Eclipse then everything is OK. Then I remove all the content of this application and install the project using .apk file. When I start the app I Facebook login is not working.

I export the project as Android Application. *At first I tried to use debug.keystore as the existing keystore, but it did not work and then tried to create a new keystore and this didn't work either.*

I tried to get a key hash but it did not help.

Could anyone explain what is the reason for this problem and how it could be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time I finally solved this problem by generating a new key hash. It was probably my 5th key hash and at least several of them were generated using a keystore that is different than debug.keystore. But this time I used a bit different method and different key hash was formed. The method I used is discribed in there:

[Signed APK has different Key-Hash for Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11864700/signed-apk-has-different-key-hash-for-facebook)